# Springboot Security and rest controller, I want to permitAll

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a springboot wab mvc application with spring-boot-starter-security and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and spring-boot-starter-data-rest.
I have a simple login page to access to a welcome user page.
adding to that I have a rest controller to delivery a web service :

MyRestController :

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/device" )
   @RestController
   public class DeviceController {

    @Autowired
    IDeviceService deviceService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveProfile", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Device> saveDeviceProfil(@RequestBody Device device) throws Throwable{
        Device deviceUpdated = deviceService.saveIfNotNull(device);
        return new ResponseEntity<Device>(deviceUpdated, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And my security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/device/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }       
}
```

When I try to access to http://localhost:8080/device/saveProfile with Postman, I receive the login page instead of may JSON object. It seems the security does'nt permit all despite my security config :

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/device/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem in adding this function in my WebSecurityConfig class :

```
@Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/device/**");
        }
```